# Redis-2.6.16 installation issue

Tags: redis, logstash

I am trying to install redis-2.6.16 on windows using cygwin. I am getting below error.
Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
/c/cygwin64/bin/cc: /c/cygwin64/bin/cc: cannot execute binary file    
make[3]: *** [net.o] Error 126
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/cygwin64/home/redis-2.6.16/deps/hiredis'  
make[2]: *** [hiredis] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/cygwin64/home/redis-2.6.16/deps'  
make[1]: [persist-settings] Error 2 (ignored)  
    CC adlist.o  
/c/cygwin64/bin/cc: /c/cygwin64/bin/cc: cannot execute binary file  
make[1]: *** [adlist.o] Error 126  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/cygwin64/home/redis-2.6.16/src'  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use basic Redis on Windows, you have to use the binaries given by the unsupported port on Windows: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

Basically, you can't just compile the C code of Redis on Windows. And this port has some drawbacks (as Windows does not support fork command), there are "stop the world" operations in it (that redis does not have in its official version): you can't use it for production.

That said, the stack says that cc is missing, you need a C compiler on cygwin, but that won't be enough to make redis work on Windows. Check the last link (github) and download the binaries if you do need to make redis work on Windows.

Comment: I downloaded redis from https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads and installed it on window. redis-server.exe is starting redis on windows. This is working as a broker between logstash shipper and indexer. @zenbeni Thanks for your help !